# Gulp error in the command line while setting Foundation 6 on Windows 10

Tags: cmd, gulp, zurb-foundation-6

I am doing a first install of Foundation 6 on my computer. After installing node.js, git, and python, I created with the command line the project folder. Then I typed the command

```
foundation watch
```

and I received the following error:

```
C:\Users\Luther\Desktop\websites\project1>foundation watch
foundation-sites-template@1.0.0 start 
C:\Users\Luther\Desktop\websites\project1
> gulp

[16:42:34] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\websites\project1\gulpfile.js
[16:42:34] Starting 'sass'...
[16:42:34] 'sass' errored after 124 ms
[16:42:34] Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (57)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v3.13.1
at module.exports (C:\Users\Luther\Desktop\websites\project1\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:13:13)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Luther\Desktop\websites\project1\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Luther\Desktop\websites\project1\node_modules\gulp-sass\index.js:187:21)
Error: foundation-sites-template@1.0.0 start: `gulp`
Exit status 1
at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Luther\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\foundation-cli\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:217:16)
at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Luther\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\foundation-cli\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try `npm rebuild node-sass`?

Comment: I tried, still the same error...